# Why is this virtual function call so expensive?

Tags: c++, c++11, performance-testing, virtual-functions

I recently modified a program to use virtual functions (in place of sequence if `if-else` conditions with static calls.)  The modified program runs 8% slower than the original.  That seems like too high of a cost for using virtual functions, so I must be doing something inefficient in the way I set the class hierarchy and virtual functions; but, I'm at a loss for how to track down the problem.  (I see similar performance degradation using both `clang` on my Mac and `gcc` on Linux.)

The program is used to study different community detection algorithms.  The program uses a nested loop to apply a series of user-specified objective functions to a variety of (graph, partition) pairs.

Here is a rough outline of the original code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bool use_m1;
    bool use_m2;
    ...
    bool use_m10;

    //  set the various "use" flags based on argv

    for (Graph& g : graphsToStudy()) {
        for (Partition& p : allPartitions()) {
            if (use_m1) {
                M1::evaluate(g, p);
            }
            if (use_m2) {
                M2::evaluate(g,p);
            }
            // and so on
        }
    }
```

To make the code easier to maintain, I created a class structure for the different objective functions, and iterated through an array of pointers:

```
class ObjectiveFunction {
public:
    virtual double eval(Graph& g, Partition& p) = 0;
}

class ObjFn1 : public ObjectiveFunction {
public:
    virtual double eval(Graph& g, Partition& p) {
        return M1::evaluate(g,p);
   }
}

class ObjFn2 : public ObjectiveFunction {
public:
    virtual double eval(Graph& g, Partition& p) {
        return M2::evaluate(g,p);
   }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<ObjectiveFunction*> funcs;
    fill_funcs_based_on_opts(funcs, argc, argv);

    for (Graph& g : graphsToStudy()) {
        for (Partition& p : allPartitions()) {
            // funcs contains one object for each function selected by user.
            for (ObjectiveFunction* fp : funcs) {
                fp->evaluate(g, p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Given that generating graphs and partitions, as well as the objective functions themselves are moderately computationally intensive, the addition of the virtual function call should be almost unnoticeable.  Any ideas what I may have done wrong; or how to track it down?  I tried using callgrind, but am not seeing any insights.

Perhaps I am just incorrectly interpreting the output of `callgrind_annotate`.  In the example below, `Neo::Context::evaluatePartition` is analogous to `ObjFn1::evaluate` in the example above.

1. Why is this function listed four different times with different
   source files?  This method is only ever called from function `main`
   in `timeMetrics.cpp`.
2. What does `src/lib/PartitionIterator.h:main` refer to?  There is no
       main function in `PartitionIterator.h`.
3. Why does 414,219,420 appear twice in the source code listing for
       `evaluatePartition`?  Isn't the first number supposed to represent
       the overhead of the function call?

---

```
35,139,513,913  PROGRAM TOTALS
17,029,020,600  src/lib/metrics/Neo.h:gvcd::metrics::Neo::Context<unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned int>::evaluatePartition(gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&, bool)  [bin/timeMetrics_v]  
7,168,741,865  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int>::buildMembersh ipList()  
4,418,473,884  src/lib/Partition.h:gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int>::buildMembershipList() [bin/timeMetrics_v]  
1,459,239,657  src/lib/PartitionIterator.h:main  
1,288,682,640  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:gvcd::metrics::Neo::Context<unsigned int, unsigned char, u nsigned int>::evaluatePartition(gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&, bool)  
1,058,560,740  src/lib/Partition.h:gvcd::metrics::Neo::Context<unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned int>::evaluatePartition(gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&, bool)  
1,012,736,608  src/perfEval/timeMetrics.cpp:main [bin/timeMetrics_v]    443,847,782  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:main 
368,372,912  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int>::buildMembersh ipList()    
322,170,738  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:main
    92,048,760  src/lib/SmallGraph.h:gvcd::metrics::Neo::Context<unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned int>::evaluatePartition(gvcd::Partition<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&, bool)
    84,549,144  ???:szone_free_definite_size [/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib]
    54,212,938  ???:tiny_free_list_add_ptr [/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib]



            .          virtual double
  414,219,420          evaluatePartition(const Partition <VertexID, SetBitmap> &p, bool raw = false) {
  414,219,420            uint_wn_t raw_answer = Neo::evaluatePartition(*(this->g), p);
            .            return (double) (raw ? raw_answer : max_neo - raw_answer);
            .          }
            .        }; // end Context
```

Comment: Tell me you didn't `#define foreach for`...

Comment: No.  The example isn't from my real code, which is much more complex because it has a lot of templates.  I taught Java for many years before returning to C++.  Old habits die hard :)

Comment: The problem may very well be that you replaced the benefit of a branch predictor with static calls for a dynamic call which is two indirections. Your virtual functions are wasting CPU cycles, which the branches did not.

Comment: Maybe also don't make copies of things that don't need to be copied?

Comment: @StoryTeller, modern CPU usually do predict indirect calls as well

Comment: The two pieces of code do different things. The first one always selects one fixed function cal based on an unchanging parameter, the second one dispatches *per element*. The latter is more powerful, hence more expensive.

Comment: @SergeyA - That would depend on the implementation of dynamic dispatch, no? But I suppose modern C++ compiler vendors are pretty consistent, so perhaps my point *is* less valid.

Comment: @KerrekSB  My first thought was that I was making an unnecessary copy; but, I'm not seeing it (either in the code, or evidence of a copy constructor being called in callgrind).

Comment: You should see it. What is `Graph g : graphsToStudy()` doing in your opinion?

Comment: Was only one of `use_mN` ever set? Maybe the compiler lifted the if outside of the loop and just generated a handful of entire loops, and dispatched to those. (Hint: this is a possible solution for you.)

Comment: @KerrekSB The dispatch is more expensive, but shouldn't that difference be almost unnoticeable as compared to the cost of the evaluation itself?

Comment: Also, the first code contains two loops, the second one three. What's in that vector?

Comment: @Zack: I don't know, I thought we're talking about the relative difference only. You can stub out the evaluation if you're interested in the cost of the dispatch only.

Comment: @StoryTeller it is a simplification of a call to an iterator that retrieves graph objects from the `nauty` graph library.  That code is the same in both versions, so the change to virtual functions should affect this part of the code.  (For what it's worth, the relevant code actually looks like this: `while (!graphIterator.atEnd()) { ... gvcd::SmallGraph<VertexID, EdgeMembershipType> &g(*graphIterator); }`

Comment: Well, when your pseudo code looks like valid C++ code with a more severe performance errors, no surprise people don't see the problem. Perhaps you oversimplified the problem away entirely, thus we will never be able to see it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think I got those fixed.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: As far as I can tell...

Comment: what about the virtual table?

Answer (score 2):

Lets fix the obvious first:

In both versions you do this:

```
foreach (Graph g : graphsToStudy()) {
    foreach (Partition p : allPartitions()) {
```

Unless Graph/Partition are easy and small to copy then most of your work will be here.

```
foreach (Graph& g : graphsToStudy()) {
           // ^
    foreach (Partition& p : allPartitions()) {
                   // ^
```

The second question I have. This does not seem like the correct usage of virtual functions. Your original code looks totally fine in this use case where multiple version of `evaluate()` are being called on each `(g, p)` object pair.

Now if you only called every one of the `evaluate()` functions then it might be a better use case, but then you no longer need that inner loop:

```
 foreach (ObjectiveFunction* fp : funcs) {
```

Comment: This risks modifying the original collection.  The compiler can help you avoid that, by using the `const` keyword for those references.

Comment: Suppose user ran `theProgram --m1 --m2 --m5`, then `funcs` contains three objects:  One for each selected function.   This loop does not iterate over all possible functions, only those that are selected for the current execution.

Answer (score 1):

It's expensive because you're actually *using* polymorphism, which defeats the branch predictor.

It may help the branch predictor if you replace collection iteration with an intrinsic linked list:

```
class ObjectiveFunction
{
    ObjectiveFunction* m_next;
    virtual double evaluate(Graph& g, Partition& p) = 0;

  protected:
    ObjectiveFunction(ObjectiveFunction* next = nullptr) : m_next(next) {}

    // for gcc use __attribute__((always_inline))
    // for MSVC use __forceinline
    void call_next(Graph& g, Partition& p)
    {
        if (m_next) m_next->eval(g, p);
    }
  public:
    virtual void eval(Graph& g, Partition& p) = 0;
};
```

Now, instead of one line of code inside the loop reaching many different functions, the `call_next()` function (which should be the last step of each individual `eval` overload) should be inlined into each of those overloads, and at runtime, each inlined copy of that indirect-call instruction will repeatedly call just one function, resulting in 100% branch prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Where I can, I prefer static over dynamic dispatch -- dynamic dispatch can cost you by preventing optimizations like function inlining, and with the double-dereference involved with vtables you can suffer from poor locality (instruction cache misses).

I suspect the lion's share of the difference in performance is from losing the benefits of optimizations performed on static dispatch.  It might be interesting to try disabling inlining on the original code to see how much of an benefit you were enjoying.